# How to upgrade 20.04.X to get all that 20.04.4 goodness

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kernel

I'm looking for some advice on how I can upgrade 100's of Ubuntu 20.04.X installations to get all that 20.04.4 goodness.

First some background:

I manage an environment where we have 100's of Ubuntu 20.04.X installations. Up until now, we've just lived with the fact that they are using lvmpipe instead of the built-in/onboard Intel graphics. Anyways for poops and giggles I decided to download the latest 20.04.4 ISO and throw it on a system and to my shock and surprise it was listed and working!

I immediately tried some upgrading of a few of our existing systems and while it did upgrade to 20.04.4, we did not enjoy the same results.

Of note, I noticed that the upgrade kept us on the 5.04 Kernel. Of course I did (and have in the past) try upgrading to the 5.13 HWE kernel and that didn't seem to work.

So I'm wondering... short of having to re-install the OS on all these systems (which really isn't an option we want to explore), does anyone know of some dark magic that I can use to upgrade an existing installation to get all the bits and parts that are obviously included on the ISO?

Comment: Someone solved this on Arch Linux with an nvidia graphics card here. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1933760#p1933760 I’d wager the principles applied will work in your case for Intel. Seems the problem was in an Xorg config file

Comment: I see three different questions here: How to go from 20.04.X to 20.04.4, how to install the HWE kernel properly, and how to fix your video card problem. AskUbuntu works best if you keep to a single question. You will get better answers if you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395950/edit) to ask a single, clear, answerable question instead of three.

Comment: "*try upgrading to the 5.13 HWE kernel and that didn't seem to work*" is too vague to offer useful advice. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/887123/can-i-switch-to-hwe-kernel-after-installation. If you still have a problem, show complete input and output of the problem in your question.

Comment: I've had no issues switching systems from GA to HWE using nothing more than details already documented (eg. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) so I concur with @user535733  You should need no more than a `sudo apt update` to update software lists; then `sudo apt full-upgrade` to upgrade packages; not the full-upgrade and not `apt upgrade`.  Some closed-source drivers don't allow GA & HWE to co-exist; but where only open-source are used (plus some closed-source) they can co-exist happily.